# Sandbox IAP returns Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" when I change subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am working with IAP, and I have a group of two subscriptions: Monthly and yearly. I created a lot of sandbox users in order to test that. When I purchase a subscription it is ok. But when I try to change (monthly to yearly or vice versa) I receive this error:

Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

My app receives the error and handle with it, but magically the subscription is signed!!! Is this a sandbox user error? I already created a lot of sandbox users, but it happened with all of them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot test a upgrade/downgrade in subscriptions with sandbox users. Try testing it with a real apple id.

Comment: But I wanna test that without being charged.

Comment: Roberto, depending on whether your product has a trial mode you can pay for it and then cancel immediately on the page [Manage subscriptions](https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions).